# XSD: restriction on type to not be empty /Blank and to exist? But its a simple type (string) inside a complexType

Tags: c#, xml, schema, xsd

I have an XSD, here is part of it defined below, but it's not working. I need to ensure that Name isn't like this

```
   <Item Name="example"></Item>
```

notice that there is nothing in between the tag, I run a validate and it passes. I have set use ="required". And I also tried setting some restrictions but it said it can only do it with a simple type. Well it is a complexType with a string inside.

```
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnItem_Text" 
                msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Item_Text" 
                msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="Item_TextColumn" 
                msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Item_Text" 
                msdata:ColumnName="Item_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string" >
            <xs:attribute name="Name"
                msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnName" 
                msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Name" 
                msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="NameColumn" 
                msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Name" type="xs:string"
                     use="required" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Precisely what do you want? Do you want to ensure that <Item> must be a non empty string?

Comment: Exactly Per,  non empty string i.e NOT empty and also NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `extension base="xs:string"`, use `extension base="non-empty-string"` where non-empty-string is a simple type defined as a restriction of xs:string using `<minLength value='1'/>` (or perhaps a regular expression, if you also want to prohibit a value containing only whitespace).

Comment: Thnaks Michael, non empty string is not declared   <xs:extension base="non-empty-string" >